# Do if statements take significant amounts of time in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, if-statement, optimization

I am creating a graphing program which has to iterate values through a calculation 10000-1000000 times, and then append part of that output to a list. In order to change which list it is appended to, there are ~3 if statements inside that loop. While it would logically be faster to use the if statement first, is there a significant amount of time saved?

As an example:

```
output = []
append_to = "pol"
for i in range(10000):
    if append_to == "pol":
        output.append(np.cos(i))
    else:
        output.append(np.sin(i))
```

Would this be significantly slower than:

```
output = []
append_to = "pol"
if append_to == "pol":
    for i in range(10000):
        output.append(np.cos(i))
else:
    for i in range(10000):
        output.append(np.sin(i))
```

Comment: Regardless of which one is faster, keep in mind they are not entirely equivalent (assuming the value of `append_to` may change, otherwise the whole question has no point)

Comment: Does `append_to` stay the same during the entire loop? In that case, you could define `f = np.cos if append_to == "pol" else np.sin` and then do `output = list(map(f, range(10000))`

Comment: Yes, append_to stays the same over the entire loop, why does this invalidate the question? I am asking about optimization. Thank you for your suggestion, i will have to look into the map function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why dont just try?

```
import numpy as np
import timeit

def one():
    output = []
    append_to = "pol"
    for i in range(10000):
        if append_to == "pol":
            output.append(np.cos(i))
        else:
            output.append(np.sin(i))

def two():
    output = []
    append_to = "pol"
    if append_to == "pol":
        for i in range(10000):
            output.append(np.cos(i))
    else:
        for i in range(10000):
            output.append(np.sin(i))

print(timeit.timeit('f()', 'from __main__ import one as f', number=1000))
print(timeit.timeit('f()', 'from __main__ import two as f', number=1000))

Output:
9.042721510999854
8.626055914000062
```

So yes, it is faster, as expected. And just for you to know the lookup also takes a bit of time, so if you do `ap = output.append` and then call `ap` instead of `output.append` you get a marginal improvement.

Answer (score 2):

Give it a try!

```
import math, time

time_start = time.time()

output = []
append_to = "pol"
for i in range(10000000):
    if append_to == "pol":
        output.append(math.cos(i))
    else:
        output.append(math.sin(i))

print("End: " + str(time.time() - time_start))
```

For that run, I got 4.278s. For this run:

```
import math, time

time_start = time.time()

output = []
append_to = "pol"
if append_to == "pol":
    for i in range(10000000):
        output.append(math.cos(i))
else:
    for i in range(10000000):
        output.append(math.sin(i))

print("End: " + str(time.time() - time_start))
```

I got 3.751s.

So there you go!